# Admin controlled page force refresh

Tags: php, ajax, comet, long-polling, page-refresh

Basically, for a website I'm playing with, I would love to craft a back-end admin controlled panel where I can click buttons that will fire events on a front-end facing page for clients. I am running an apache server and coding exclusively in PHP/JavaScript.

I've been reading about long-polling and it seems to be the best route from what I've read, but I have no experience in this. Also, the fact that I'm running apache seems to be a problem from what I've read here. I have complete access to the server (VPS), so I could technically install node.js to set up long-polling, but I also have no experience with this.

What would be the best route for me to take for my given situation? Long-polling? Comet-based? A technology I've completely missed?

Any example links would greatly help as well.

Comment: Since you have a VPS, you could set up node with [socket.io](http://socket.io). You also have a few comet services to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:

[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

Pretty much covers what you're looking for.